# Git strategy needed to get an old source code in Git and manage it to have a single point to maintain code

Tags: git, version-control

I looked on the web for several days but can't find an answer to my problem.
Maybe I have more luck here.

This is the problem I'm facing, I have several old codebases, say 30 and through the years it grew by copy and past and adding custom code to each codebase. For the record, none of them are in any way managed by any type of source control now.

Now I want to use GIT to control all the sources. The main goal I want to achieve is to create a new Master repository from all the different code sources and make sure that if a part gets into the new Master repo it can from thereon be maintained into one place.

Here are some of the ideas I have and please correct me if I'm saying things wrong.

1. Creating a new repo of the best codebase I have and make a branch for each codebase inside this new repo. This way I can eventually merge the good parts of each codebase into the Master. So in time, the Master will gather all the best parts and I can pull the best code back into each separate codebase. Every new bugfix will then be fixed in the Master and pulled by all the others.
2. Create a new Master repo and use patching to gather all the pieces from the different codebases. But how can I maintain the code in a proper way and do bug fixing in one place?
   Do I have to patch it back into each separate codebase? Or do I change the remote and pull/push it back?
3. Create a new Master repo and use cherry-picking to gather al the pieces from the different codebases. But how can I maintain the code in a proper way and do bug fixing in one place? Do I have to `cherry-pick` it back into each separate codebase? Or do I change the remote and pull/push it back?

If anybody should have any info, tips or whatever please share because I'm sure there will be more people facing this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes approximate 70% of each codebase is similar but every codebase has it's own custom code.

Answer (score 5):

### One project one repository

For each of your projects it will be a checkout and a repository.

You could make one repository and 30 branches, but there's no obvious benefit in doing that and it will make standard practices harder to do (e.g. [git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) is a common working model, simply having 30 branches will itself be cumbersome).

If you have 30 projects that are using 70% similar code, you need to choose between having one repository for each of your projects, or, one repository for each *subproject* of your code base.

For example, if all 30 projects have an identical "awesome" folder - that would be a project in itself, and included as a submodule. This would permit easier maintenance and no duplication of code (and no copy and paste either).

*If* setup appropriately in the beginning, it's quite easy to change things if at a later date you decide/realize that the structure of your repository/submodules doesn't match what you need.

### Aim to achieve common history

If you have 30 projects with 70% code, you can pick one of them to be your "base" project and therefore logically have:

```
baseproject
   |- project 1.1
   |- project 1.2
   |- project 1.3
```

If you already maintain a folder that you use to copy-and-paste for new projects *that* is your base project; the above bears no cronological meaning (base project does not mean it was created before 1.1 etc.).

### Initializing your git repositories

Let's assume for the sake of illustration you have two project trees:

```
base
    README.md

project1.1
    README.md
    src/file
```

#### initialize your base repository

Here are some example contents, which will later permit seeing how history changes:

```
$ cd /base
$ echo "base readme" > README.md
```

Initialize the git repository and commit all files in your base project:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /base/.git
$ git add README.md
$ git commit -m "Adding base readme"
[master (root-commit) e7ec2b5] Adding base readme
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 README.md
```

#### Initialize subprojects

Here are some differences from the base project:

```
$ cd /project1.1
$ echo "project 1.1" > README.md
$ mkdir src
$ echo "project 1.1 src file" > src/file
```

Then initialize the git repository:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /project1.1/.git
```

Don't commit the contents yet.

#### Link to the base project

Add a remote so that each project is linked to the base project. This permits, if nothing else, changes which are applied to the base project's code to be *trivially* pulled into your subprojects:

```
$ git remote add base /base/.git
$ git fetch base
$ git reset base/master
```

At this time, `project 1.1` has the git history of the base project, but no files have been modified in the working copy.

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   README.md
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   src/
```

Committing differences to already tracked files (the `README.md` file):

```
$ git commit -am "modifications to base files"
```

And then committing the currently-untracked files (the `src` folder):

```
$ git add *
$ git commit -am "project 1.1 specific files"
```

This will mean that the project has a history of 3 commits:

```
$ git log --oneline
22a82d7 project 1.1 specific files
951f32a modifications to base files
e7ec2b5 adding base readme
```

In this way, you can maintain your "base" changes in one place and optionally pull back changes made in one project to your base project.

Comment: Thx for the great feedback, and I  will try it out this weekend and get back here then.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to create a repository for each codebase. Putting unrelated code into one big repository dilutes the benefits of source control.

Following your comment I think what you should look at are git submodules. It gives you a single repository which you can share with other repositories. Also, if you make a change to the common code in one project you can push this to the master repository where it is the available to other repositories should they wish to use the changes.

Comment: No the Master repository would be the single point to spawn new projects in the future instead of copy/past, so the code is related to each other and is one application.

Comment: this is especially true for git. For some other vcs's, such as for svn or clearcase, having one big repo is more manageable with partial checkouts and specific config specs. But for git, that's not the way to go.

Comment: Thx and yes it's more a thing I need. But while looking into submodules I also found the Tree-merge. So what's the difference?    I understood that I have to use less commands to have the same behavior. Checking it this weekend.

Answer (score 1):

Put each codebase into a separate repository and then create one more repository to serve as your "super-repo" which can contain all the others. Add all the individual repositories to the super-repo as submodules. This lets them keep separate histories while giving you a way to keep track of them all in a single location.

Read more on [submodules here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).